# ImageElement OnClick Event

Tags: dom, script#

How can I atatch an onclick event to an ImageElement in using ScriptSharp?

I'm getting an error when i'm trying this:

```
 ImageElement Button = (ImageElement)Document.CreateElement("img");
        Button.Src = "image.png";
        Button.AddEventListener("click", delegate(ElementEvent e)
        {
            Script.Alert("Clicked");
        }, false);
```

It works when I view the page in Google Chrome, but not in IE8...
So I guess that ScriptSharp cant create code to use with IE < 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The github issue alsoo covers this - https://github.com/NikhilK/scriptsharp/issues/1

In short, I'd recommend either an existing wrapper, like jQuery, or your own custom one that abstracts the eventing differences and support for DOM events in different browsers, rather than conditionally calling attachEvent from within app code.

In general script#, as the compiler, doesn't do abstraction of differences across browsers - frameworks do that. This is folks either have their own abstractions, or framework choices they've already made, and often opinions about how the abstractions should work.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with how you are using the DOM. IE7 through 8 does not support `addEventListener`. You need to use `attachEvent` or a library that wraps the differences between the browsers (such as jQuery).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener